# My question is related to finding if a set of vectors form a basis.

Tags: vector-spaces

For what value of K the set of vectors {(k,1,1), (0,1,1), (k,0,k)}
form a basis in R^3?

Till now I have tried to check for the linear independence, using which I get that the value of k should not be 0, i.e, I put the Determinant of coefficient Matrix as not equal to zero.

However I am unsure how to proceed to eliminate values of k while checking if the vectors span R^3.

Comment: I don't understand what step you ended at.  You should have taken the determinant of the matrix formed with those as your rows (*or columns, doesn't matter*) and you should have gotten a polynomial as a result.  You set that polynomial equal to zero you say.  You correctly identified that the polynomial had $k$ as a factor.  Are there any other factors?  If not, what should that imply?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic process (set determinant of matrix of coefficient matrix not equal to zero) sounds correct.  Hopefully, without giving anything away I'll say that the polynomial you get from this is particularly simple (I'm not going to say what the polynomial is, but maybe you should say what it is to show some of the work you've done and give more direction on what you need help with).

It might be good to back up and think intuitively.  We are in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  So, for any "random" set of three vectors we choose in $\mathbb{R}^3$, how can the set of vectors **fail** to form a basis?  Can you state in geometric terms how they would fail to form a basis?  Now can you apply that geometric intuition to this case?  In particular, based on this intuition, do you believe that there is a single value of $k$ that solves this, a finite set of values of $k$, or an infinite set of values?